# How to put a uint8_t in the middle of uint16_t without affecting other bits

Tags: c, embedded, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am writing a SPI driver for a DAC chip which uses 16bit SPI messages...the value that represents the output is from bit 11 to bit 4 (an 8 bit DAC). I have wrote this MASK but I have no idea how to achieve updating the data without affecting other bits:

```
#define MCP4901_SPI_MASK_DATA               0x0FF0
//So data mask in binary is 0000 1111 1111 0000

extern uint16_t mcpA;

static inline void mcpSetData(uint16_t* mcp, uint8_t value) {
    //????
   *mcp =| value & MCP4901_SPI_MASK_DATA; //NOT WORKING
}
```

Comment: Why would you write part of a SPI data register and not all of it? That doesn't make any sense. Is there some sort of intricate "daisy chain" hardware?

Comment: @Lundin There are other config bits too (bits 15-12), I could do set them as they are single bit , my problem was just shifting a 8bit DAC value to position 11 to 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct about the use of the two operations `|` and `&`, but you are not using them in the right order, and you are not positioning one of the operands correctly.

Here is the correct way of doing it:

```
*mcp &= ~MCP4901_SPI_MASK_DATA; // Clear out the middle bits
*mcp |= ((uint16_t)value) << 4; // Put in the value in the middle
```

Since you are writing to a hardware register, a single write should be used to avoid possible side effects:

```
*mcp = (*mcp & ~MCP4901_SPI_MASK_DATA) | (((uint16_t)value) << 4);
```

`MCP4901_SPI_MASK_DATA` is inverted to clear out bits outside of `0x0FF0`. Alternatively, you could define the mask as `0xF00F`, and drop the `~` operator.

The 8-bit value is shifted left by 4 to position it in the middle of 16 bits before "OR"-ing it into the number.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/aGnq06)

Comment: I'd be very careful about writing to a SPI data register several times in a row. A write or read could have side effects, such as flags getting cleared or data being sent. Depends on the specific hardware.

Comment: @Lundin You are right, I completely missed the fact that OP is writing to a hardware register. Thank  you!

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for bringing up the discussion. I used that `mcpSetData()` function just to update the content of a U16 variable...other bits and settings are done with other functions. When the desired data is ready I push it to the SPI using a single command (HAL_SpiTransmit from STM32). It works fine now :)